# Selecting minimum time for each unique column value where user is not banned

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a bunch of player records, a bunch of world records, and a bunch of banned players:

`describe records`

```
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| type   | varchar(3)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| map    | varchar(31)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| authid | varchar(31)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time   | decimal(13,6) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date   | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`describe wrs`

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| map         | varchar(31)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| route       | varchar(31)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| time        | decimal(5,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`describe banned`

```
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| authid | varchar(31) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I am trying to select the minimum `time` from the `records` table for each unique `map` where `authid` (a player identifier) is not found in the `banned` table.

I also want to retrieve the world record `time` from `wrs` for the same `map`.

I would like to select `map`, `authid`, and `time` from `records` only if `type` equals "pro" but would like to keep `map` from the list of unique maps and `time` from the corresponding row in `wrs` if the `type` does not equal "pro".

My issue is retrieving the correct/corresponding `authid` from the `records` table when retrieving the minimum `time`/`map`. I've managed to do something like this:

```
SELECT m.map, minTime, wrTime, wrTime / minTime AS ratio, minTime - wrTime AS diffTime FROM
    # get all unique maps from records table
    (SELECT map FROM records GROUP BY map) AS m
        LEFT JOIN
    # find min time for each map where type is pro
    (SELECT type, map, MIN(time) AS minTime FROM records WHERE type = "pro" GROUP BY map) AS p
        ON m.map = p.map
        LEFT JOIN
    # find world record time for each map
    (SELECT map, MIN(time) AS wrTime FROM wrs GROUP BY map) AS w
        ON m.map = w.map
```

but it does not account for banned players because I cannot retrieve the correct `authid` values when selecting the minimum `time` (aside: I am not even sure the correct `type` would be used in the where clause). I could easily add something like the following to the query to ignore banned players if I had the proper `authid`:

```
SELECT * FROM records r LEFT JOIN banned b ON r.authid = b.authid WHERE b.authid IS NULL
```

Hopefully I've made sense. If not, please ask for more information.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected results? If you could do it at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com), that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I understood your problem completely, but I think the following SQL might help you with:

> My issue is retrieving the correct/corresponding authid from the records table when retrieving the minimum time/map. "

```
SELECT
    map,
    MIN(time) AS minTime
FROM records
WHERE
    authid NOT IN (SELECT authId FROM banned)
GROUP BY map
```

Comment: Thanks, Felix, for reformatting my badly formatted post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope I didn't mistake your intendance.

```
SELECT
    m.map,
    m.minTime,
    w.wrTime,
    w.wrTime / m.minTime AS ratio,
    m.minTime - w.wrTime AS diffTime
FROM
    records r
    INNER JOIN
    -- get all unique maps from records table
    (SELECT map, MIN(time) AS minTime FROM records WHERE type = "pro" GROUP BY map) m ON r.map = m.map AND r.time = m.minTime
    LEFT JOIN
    -- find world record time for each map
    (SELECT map, MIN(time) AS wrTime FROM wrs GROUP BY map) w ON m.map = w.map
    LEFT JOIN banned b ON r.authid = b.authid
WHERE b.authid IS NULL
```

Comment: I believe this doesn't count a row if the minimum time is from a banned player.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, this is how I ended up solving my problem (with the help of Piyg's answer):

```
SELECT
    m.map,
    p.minTime,
    w.wrTime,
    w.wrTime / p.minTime AS ratio,
    p.minTime - w.wrTime AS diffTime
FROM
    (SELECT
        map
    FROM records
    GROUP BY map) m
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        map,
        MIN(time) AS minTime
    FROM records
    WHERE
        authid NOT IN (SELECT authid FROM banned)
    AND
        type = "pro"
    GROUP BY map) p
ON m.map = p.map
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        map,
        MIN(time) AS wrTime
    FROM wrs
    GROUP BY map) w
ON m.map = w.map
```

Comment: glad that my answer could help.